Visual Studio couldn't link to dlls - git lfs problem
Bottom line - git lfs wasn't installed
I pushed some 3rd party dlls to my repo at one PC. I marked the dlls to be a git lfs registry.
At another PC I cloned the repo, and the project didn't compile. All those dlls where marked as having warning at the project > dependencies > assemblies view. VS doesn't give out any information why.
After some back and forth I found that all those dlls size was 1kb. suspicious. Inside them I saw it had text like:
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:bb75feeaa6728cf129d14f24449784d9475b0e317f222186efe2efb5ffae680c
size 8192

That means that at that PC git lfs wasn't installed, and for some reason it doesn't come with VS, and git deosn't warn about it.
anyway, installing git lfs and running git lfs pull fixed the problem.

Installing git lfs and running git lfs pull fixed the problem.
